# Null pointer while trying to access Bean

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, spring-bean

I have a configuration class which creates multiple beans:

```
@Configuration
public class TopLevelConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyMapper myMapper() {
        MyMapper mapper = new MyMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new MetadataModule());
        return new MyMapper();
    }
}
```

Now in MetadataModule:

```
@Override
public void setupModule(final SetupContext setupContext) {
    final SimpleDeserializers deserializers = new SimpleDeserializers();

    deserializers.addDeserializer(Payload.class, new PayloadDeserializer());
    setupContext.addDeserializers(deserializers);
}
```

In `PayloadDeserializer` I'm not able to autowire the `MyMapper` class. I'm thinking this is because when the new Object of `PayloadDeserializer` is created, the bean of `MyMapper` hasn't been created by then. How do I allow `PayloadDeserializer` to get access to the bean object?

Comment: Can you post the Null Pointer Exception? That might give a clue

Comment: @DavidD The NPE is because myMapper is null in PayloadDeserializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `PayloadDeserializer` object by yourself by calling `new PayloadDeserializer()`, this is the reason why `MyMapper` is not injected to it. To inject/autowire to work, your bean should be spring managed. To do that, you can use `@Component` on top of your `PayloadDeserializer` class like below.

```
@Component
public class PayloadDeserializer {
    private final MyMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    public PayloadDeserializer(MyMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class TopLevelConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyMapper myMapper(PayloadDeserializer payloadDeserializer) {
        MyMapper mapper = new MyMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(metadataModule(payloadDeserializer));
        return mapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public MetadataModule metadataModule(PayloadDeserializer payloadDeserializer) {
        return new MetadataModule(payloadDeserializer);
    }
}

public class MetadataModule {
    private final PayloadDeserializer payloadDeserializer;
    public MetadataModule(PayloadDeserializer payloadDeserializer) {
        this.payloadDeserializer = payloadDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(final SetupContext setupContext) {
        final SimpleDeserializers deserializers = new SimpleDeserializers();

        deserializers.addDeserializer(Payload.class, payloadDeserializer);
        setupContext.addDeserializers(deserializers);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the part where you used Autowire on the constructor. Can't we use Autowire directly on the member variable?

Comment: In your example you call metadataModule() without any parameters but in the definition you keep parameter as PayloadDeserializer.

Comment: We can use autowire directly on member, but The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection. https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/

Comment: When does the Object of PayloadDeserializer get created? Because PayloadDeserializer requires myMapper in its constructor, but by it is already passed as an object before initialization of myMapper.

Comment: I get a runtime error saying Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'payloadDeserializer': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Comment: Bcz of using component annotation in PayloadDeserializer, the object is auto created by spring for injection. The problem you are facing is bcz of circular dependency. Can you post your actual classes for PayloadDeserializer and MyMapper and MetadataModule? It will be helpful to understand your scenario.

Comment: Check this to avoid circular dependency exception. http://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring